# slideToggle and onClick not working when put in wordpress site

Tags: jquery, wordpress, onclick, slidetoggle

```js
$('#comment-button').click(function () {
    $('#comment-panel').slideToggle();
});
```

```css
#comment-button {
    padding: 3px 5px;
    background: #dddeee;
    border: 1px solid #cccddd;
}
#comment-panel {
    display: none;
    background: #dddeee;
    width: 300px;
    height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div id="comment-button">Button</div>
<div id="comment-panel">Comments</div>
```

I tried doing a slideToggle and it seemed to work fine on jsfiddle. But when I tried using the same code on my wordpress site it's not working. I did put the script in js file and enqueued it prorerly on theme functions as well. I wonder what could possibly be the issue on it.

EDIT: Seems that it's not working in snippet too. It's fine on the jsfiddle page though: jsfiddle(dot)net/3c1gjzg0/

Comment: Did you check your console?  Are there any JavaScript errors there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put javascript code into `jQuery( document ).ready()` and replace the `$` by `jQuery`. Please try the following code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery('#comment-button').click(function () {
       jQuery('#comment-panel').slideToggle();
   });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It's now working with jQuery instead of $.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code in a fuction and pass $ as a variable like this:

```
(function($) {

//Put all your code in this fuction
$('#comment-button').click(function () {
    $('#comment-panel').slideToggle();
});

})( jQuery );
```